# Questions Regarding WordPress' Site Icon Functionality and Output

Tags: wordpress, favicon

Using WordPress 4.7 and the Site Icon functionality to favicon/site icon, and it seems to be working, but the results seem odd to me, though I admit I'm far from an expert on this and have read a lot of conflicting info on best practices. Setting an image using WP's Site Icon setting results in 4 links in the  section:

`<link rel="icon" href="https://www.examle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-test-favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />`

`<link rel="icon" href="https://www.examle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-test-favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />`

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="https://www.examle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-test-favicon-180x180.png" />`

`<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://www.examle.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-test-favicon-270x270.png" />`

But it creates 10 different versions of the site icon image in addition to the original at sizes of 32x32, 100x100, 150x150, 180x180, 192x192, 250x250, 270x270, 300x300, 360x360, 500x310.

Why so many cropped images if only 4 linked to?

Also, I submit an icon image sized 512x512 as recommended, but the 500x310 version is always cropped so the top and bottom of the icon is cut off. Is there any way around this and/or is it a big deal? What is this sized icon used for?

What browser/device support does this WP Site Icon cover?

This also does not create a favicon.ico file in the site root, should I still include that or is it no longer necessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of [RealFaviconGenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net) and its companion [WordPress Favicon plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/favicon-by-realfavicongenerator/), so I'm both qualified and biased to answer this question.

The many variants you mention are useless. They *might* have been referenced by external files such as the Web App Manifest (for Android Chrome) or `browserconfig.xml` (for IE/Edge), but theses files are neither generated nor declared. So you just get useless (and harmless) images.

The 500x310 image is probably for the Windows "wide" tile. Here are an example of the 4 different tile shapes and sizes:

[image]

But these 4 images should be declared either in the HTML of via `browserconfig.xml`, which they are not. So yes, the fact that your image was cropped to generate a non-square image is a problem (your web site logo is probably ruined in the process), but a problem no one will ever notice.

WordPress Site icon covers almost all platforms. All major platforms can deal with the Apple Touch icon, which is generated and declared. The only icon you really miss is the Mask icon for macOS (used for pinned tabs and the new MacBook Touch Bar).

Only legacy browsers will really miss the old `favicon.ico`. I can't remember which generation of IE need it, but they must be quite old (think: IE on XP or maybe Vista). Most of the time that shouldn't be an issue. Better not clutter your WordPress install with manually edited files.

The other point to mention is the design itself. WordPress does a very decent effort to present you the final icons:

[image]

However, with my particular icon, there is a problem: my image is not designed to have its corners rounded that way. This is not WordPress's fault: iOS will round them no matter what. Same with transparent images:

[image]

iOS fills transparency with black so WordPress is accurate. But it offers no workaround. This is "take it or leave it".

There is another issue with design: each platform comes with its own style. Currently the Site Icon has a one-size-fits-all approach. This is okay but not great. And again, it misses the icon for macOS.

Sometimes, themes also come with their own favicon support. As far as I know, this support is always light, covering only the classic, desktop icon. The WordPress Site Icon is definitely better.

As a WordPress user, you have basically two choices:

- Use the builtin WordPress Site Icon. This is a good solution if your icon does not need modifications (eg. it has an opaque background) and you don't need the icon for macOS.
- Use [Favicon by RealFaviconGenerator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/favicon-by-realfavicongenerator/). It covers everything and let you craft your icon platform-per-platform. You know exactly how your icon will look like on your visitor's devices. This is yet another plugin to install, although it is lightweight. Again, I'm the author of this plugin so expect nothing but appraisal from me :)

Comment: Hi Philippe. I didn't mention it in my original post, but I was deciding between WP's Site Icon setting & your plugin. I ended up going with your plugin, for many of the reasons you list above. Thanks for it, it's really great.

Might have a few suggestions w/ the .htaccess rules if you're taking them. Not sure what's best practice, but I prefer plugins that delineate their own space in the file with something like `# BEGIN All In One WP Security`. Seems like it would prevent possible conflicts or overridden code if other plugins editing same section where WP's default permalink rules are.

Comment: You could also eliminate a couple lines if you did something like:

`RewriteRule ^android-chrome-([x0-9-]+)\.png$ /wp-content/uploads/fbrfg/android-chrome-$1.png [QSA,L]`

and the same for the favicon16/32 files.

Just some ideas. Thanks again for the info and the plugin!